# How to djangocms-link to a app-hook subpage?

Tags: python, django-cms

I have an app that provides a form to create and update "Prediction"s.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^create/$', PredictionCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PredictionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
   url(r'^$', PredictionListView.as_view(), name='list'),
)
```

The app is attached with an app-hook to Django CMS 3.0.12.

cms_app.py:

```
class Predictionhook(CMSApp):
    name = "Predictionhook"
    urls = ["prediction.urls"]
    app_name = "prediction"

apphook_pool.register(Predictionhook)
```

Is there an easy way to include the 'create' URL of the attached app in the list of possible choices of pages in the djangocms-link plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The standard setup won't do it as far as I'm aware.

I'd create your own copy of djangocms-link and extend it to give a field to take the same thing you'd put in a template URL tag. Then just set up the template to render that field value as a standard Django URL template tag.

So in your new field of the link app you'd add `prediction:create` and then in the template being rendered you'd have `{% url link.myurllinkfield %}`